# Sharepoint Column Fields not available on upload

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

I have created a site content type based on an inherited parent type,

Currently when I create a new document, all the relevant fields appear in the dialog.  But if I **upload** a document these two fields (`Grouping` and `Subgrouping`) that I have created are not populated in the dialog form.

Could someone advise why this is possible?

Comment: Have you added this two fields in your content type?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure below two things:

1. You have added these `Grouping` and `Subgrouping` to your newly created content type.
2. You have set your content type as default content type from **Change new button order and default content type** settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are both under the default content type and this content type is currently the default.

[image]